# choose the data from the table where COUNT of columns goes from max to min

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select, count

I have a table of questions, I need to show tha TOP of 20 questions. And I need to SELECT where count goes from max count to min.

e.g: I have 20 questions of What? and 30 questions of Wat?
here it is shown: 
Wat? | 30
What? | 20

```
SELECT *, COUNT(question) AS q 
FROM stat_otp_questions ".$filter."  
GROUP BY question ORDER BY q  LIMIT 20
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can say `ORDER BY q DESC` so it sort descending